# RSpec --tag exclude not working

Tags: rspec, filter, tags, rspec2

I have examples like this in my spec file:

```
it "does something", :separate=> true do 
end
```

for tests I want to run separately from others. These two command lines,

```
rspec --tag separate spec/models
rspec --tag @separate spec/models
```

both work to run only the tagged examples. However, I can't seem to *exclude* those examples. None of these work:

```
rspec --tag ~@separate spec/models
rspec --tag -@separate spec/models
rspec --tag ~separate spec/models
rspec --tag -separate spec/models
```

With the tilde "~" the tag is ignored entirely and all the examples are run. With the hyphen "-", rspec looks for a tag value of "-separate" or "-@separate" and generates a notice like

```
Run filtered using {:"-separate"=>true}
No examples were matched.
```

(The documentation uses the hyphen while the output of `rspec --help` uses the tilde for negation.)

What am I doing wrong?

(RSpec-core 2.5.1, RSpec-rails 2.5.0, Ubuntu 10.04 32-bit running in VirtualBox)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the tilde is the correct way to exclude tags, but it was bugged or not fully implemented in 2.5. Compare [2.6rc](http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-6-rc/dir/command-line/tag-option) to [2.5](http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-5/dir/command-line/tag-option).

Try upgrading to the pre-release 2.6

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I haven't been able to try it since I can't get 2.6.0.rc6 to work with rspec-rails, so will just wait a while.